# ReactJS memory leak at reloading Img source

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have written a multipage app using ReactJS. When a page/component with an  is re-rendered, the browser memory increases. It seems the memory is not cleared when the component is unmounted. I expect the browser memory to decrease when the component is unmounted. Does anyone have a suggestion how to clear the memory for this image at unmount?

thanks,

Tim

```
import React from 'react';

export class About extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id='about' >
          <div className="container">

            <div className="row">

              <div className="col-md-6">
                <h2>title</h2>
                <p>getting your ideas made</p>
              </div>
              <div className="col-md-6">
                <img src="app/images/pic3.png" alt=""/>
              </div>

            </div>

          </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

## update:

Below is the Parent component that the page is mounted to:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import {RightPane} from './components/RightPane.js'
import {LeftPane} from './components/LeftPane.js'
import {ModelLibrary} from './components/ModelLibrary.js'
import {ProjectsListing} from './components/ProjectsListing.js'
import {About} from './components/page_about.js'
import {Renderer} from './components/Renderer.js'


function MainSwitch(view){

  switch (view) {
    case 'listing':

      return <ProjectsListing />

      break;
    case 'viewer':
      return (
        <div>
          <Renderer />
          <LeftPane />
          <RightPane />
        </div>
      )
      break;

    case 'about':
      return <About />
      break;

    default:
      return (
        <div>
          <Renderer />
        </div>
      )

  }
}

export class ReactRoot extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state={
      mainpage:''
    }
  }

  showPage = (event)=>{
    console.log(event.detail);
    this.setState({
      mainpage:event.detail
    })
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    window.addEventListener('page-change', this.showPage, false);
  }
  componentWillUnMount(){
    window.removeEventListener('page-change', this.showPage, false);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div >
        <div id='mainpage'>
          {MainSwitch(this.state.mainpage)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please, can you reproduce the problem with at least a code snippet? There are a lot of questions to your question, e. g. how do you trigger your component unmounting, etc.

Comment: This is a 100% normal component. It doesn't even run any functions. If anything, the source must be from the parent or parent's parents. Can you show these components?

Comment: I see no mem leak in the code provided. In my experience mem leaks from images came from not releasing onload handlers on the image

Comment: thanks for your responses. I've added the parent component to the initial question.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything looks like it could be leaking... Is your About component as simple as the one you posted, or is this simplified? If it's this simple, I would remove constructor, lifecycle methods, and maybe even turn it into a Function component - this way you're sure nothing leaks from there :)

Comment: Hi @FabioLolli , I have simplified it to isolate the problem. Thanks for the advice

Comment: dear @Andrew, 
thanks for your quick response yesterday. Could you have another look at my updated question? thanks in advance